# Given a binary string return the position 000 is in position 0, 001 is in position 1. In a function

Tags: python, list, binary

Given a list that has some value such as [0,0,0]

I wish to locate its position, and by that I mean:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

the position is 0. If it  were 010 the position is 2. If it were 101 the position is 5. Basically count from 0 until you are at the position. It would be easy hard coding this if it were just three value.

But say im given [1,0,0,0] or greater. Is there a trivial way to get its position?

```
def binposition(L):
    pass
```

Not sure how to begin

Comment: is `L` your position?

Comment: L has the binary value. like 000 is L[0,0,0], so binposition(L[0,0,0]) should return 0

Comment: If you count from 0 the position is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a string which contains your binary position to an integer, and then use it as the index of your list:

```
def binposition(binary_position, L):
    return L[int(binary_position, 2)]
```

Examples:

```
>>> L = list(range(10))
>>> binposition('111', L)
7
>>> binposition('101', L)
5
```

You can also extend the class `list`, and define the method `__getitem__` as follows:

```
class L(list):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return list.__getitem__(self, int(key, 2))

>>> l = L()
>>> l.extend(list(range(10)))
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> l['111']
7
>>> l['001']
1
```

Comment: L doesnt contain the whole string just the binary value

Comment: @mammywood, I just updated my answer, I think that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the binary numbers in L to string so that you can use the `int` constructor convert it as a base 2 string:

```
def binposition(L):
    return int(''.join(map(str, L)), 2)
```

so that `binposition([1, 0, 1, 1])` returns: `11`